# Abrir pergunta duplicada

Tags: debate, recompensa, perguntas-duplicadas

É possível colocar uma recompensa em uma pergunta que foi fechada por ser duplicada? pois o autor pode não ter adaptado a resposta (ou pegado a ideia da resolução problema) da pergunta que supostamente teve seu conteúdo duplicado.

Comment: Quer colocar o exemplo em questão?

Comment: Na verdade antes você precisa mostrar que a pergunta não é duplicada. Não é possível colocar recompensa nem mesmo responder perguntas fechadas. E nada impede você de colocar uma recompensa em uma pergunta que não é sua.

Comment: @Math mas como dito se o autor não conseguiu adaptar a resposta ou pegar a ideia da resposta que foi "copiada" então não há sentido ele colocar uma recompensa nela.

Comment: A última frase minha era para caso as perguntas realmente sejam duplicadas. Caso não sejam duplicadas você precisa demonstrar isso antes de qualquer outra ação para manter a sua pergunta aberta.

Comment: O que o Math quer dizer é que a pergunta precisa ser reaberta para que se possa colocar recompensa nela.

Comment: @bfavaretto, ai esbarramos no problema para ser reaberta ela deve ser modificada e isso pode não ser possível se tudo que poderia ser explicado já esta na pergunta fechada.

Comment: Fica complicado discutir esses casos assim, de maneira abstrata. Não quer colocar o link da pergunta que originou sua dúvida?

Comment: @bfavaretto esta dúvida me veio a memória pois a alguns meses tive uma pergunta sobre SQL que foi marcada como duplicada de outra, confesso que eram parecidas (mas tinham resultados diferentes) mas mesmo não sendo iguais foi marcada como duplicada e não consegui reabrir (era sempre re-marcada como duplicada), consegui resolver o problema mas e se não tivesse? na época eu tinha pontos de reputação suficientes para pagar uma recompensa mas não consegui "pagar" por uma ajuda pelo fato dela esta marcada como duplicada.

Comment: Eu acho que encontrei a tal pergunta. Lá você mesmo tinha comentado que queria deletá-la! Enfim, eu não estou entendendo muita coisa. Perguntas fechadas não podem receber respostas, então não faz sentido colocar recompensa.